# Detect Note changes with onChange

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is it possible for Google Sheets to detect when you've edited your notes or inserted a new one using onChange?

```
function onChange(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Current");
  var r = ss.getActiveCell();

  if(e.changeType == 'OTHER') {
    if ((r.getColumn() < 7 || r.getColumn() > 7) && (ss.getName()=="Completed") && (r.getRow() > 1)) { // 2. If Edit is done in any column before or after 6th Column (F) And sheet name is Sheet1 then:
      var celladdress ='G'+ r.getRowIndex() // Add time stamp to cell in Column F
      ss.getRange(celladdress).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-08:00", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"));
      ss.getRange(r.getRow(), 17).setValue(s.getRange(row, 2).getNote());
    }
  }
```

I tried changeType FORMAT, EDIT, and OTHER and none of them works. If onChange is not possible to detect note editing, is there a function that does?

Comment: It appears to me that neither onEdit nor onChange will detect that event.  But rest assure if I'm wrong, someone will let us know.

Comment: If you want to test both onChange and onEdit at the same time you can do something like this:

    `function onMyChange(e) {
      e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1').setValue(JSON.stringify(e));
    }
    
    function onMyEdit(e) {
      e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange('B1').setValue(JSON.stringify(e));
    }`

Then you can make changes to a sheet and watch the event object be written directly into your sheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Explanation / Issue:

It took me an hour to figure this out, but actually your logic is correct.

- When editing/inserting a note `e.changeType` returns `OTHER`, therefore this part of the code is correct.

I tested your code and I also tried to get the active cell with many different ways: `getActiveCell()`, `getCurrentCell()` and `getActiveRange()` since the event object of an `onChange` trigger does not support `e.range`.

- But **every single** time `r.getColumn()` and `r.getRow()` returned `1` and `1` and when I ran the exact same code manually, I was getting the correct cell.
- I searched online and I found that this behaviour has **not only** been reported but also **accepted** by google as a **bug** and it concerns the `onChange` trigger. You can find the link [HERE](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/38159142) and make sure you star (top-left corner) the issue to make it more popular.

Since `r.getRow()` is `1` your code does not do anything because you have `r.getRow() > 1` as a condition which always evaluates to `false` because of this bug.

As a proof of this bug, you can use this code instead and you will see that when you insert or modify a note in the sheet `Completed`, the timestamp will be pasted in cell `G1` of the same sheet.

```
function onChange(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Current");
  if(e.changeType == 'OTHER') {
    if (ss.getName()=="Completed") {
      var celladdress ='G1';
      ss.getRange(celladdress).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-08:00", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"));
    }
  }
}
```

While this answer does not answer your question, it proves that your logic is correct but due to a bug you are not getting the expected results. Therefore, I thought it would be useful for you and other future readers to be aware of the issue. Unfortunately, I didn't come up with a solution but I hope another reader would do.

For all the above, I assume you have installed the [onChange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) trigger since it is an installable trigger.

Comment: @TheMaster, yes I had also mentioned that in the answer :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What I realized was that ss always returns the leftmost sheet regardless of which active sheet it was, so if I have multiple sheets, `ss.getName()=="Completed"` will always fail the condition. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: Can't reproduce your issue. Active sheet is the sheet you have selected in the `ui` ( in the spreadsheet file) @BrandonPark

Comment: Here's a sample sheet that reproduces my issue. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pVfIv6NRybK8JH-FgzTLYiTkzu73-8iD77HFZOGk3iA/edit#gid=0

Comment: @BrandonPark could you please post a new question regarding that issue so we can have two different threads? In this way future readers can find them both easier. Stackoverflow does not allow for follow up questions. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: I have created a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65851513/active-sheet-always-being-leftmost-sheet-on-google-sheets